# SOAP Dependency missing on project build

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, libraries

Just built a java thing in Netbeans, I have .jar that rely on SOAP that I have bundled in the project .jar, so I'm doubting the issues lies with any dependencies that I have to place on the CLASSPATH or something. Running in the debugger or through the IDE works perfectly fine. When I try to run my built JAR, I encounter these errors:

```
EXCEPTION: Class com.systinet.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler or one of its components not found in root.wasp-impl.SOAP

Traces : 
=====================
Class space : com.idoox.wasp.ClassSpace@8f4fb3(com.idoox.wasp.classloader.WaspClassLoader@228a02) : root.wasp-impl.SOAP : SOAP
Class path :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.systinet.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.systinet.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler
```

Am I somehow missing my ability to create SOAP requests by just building the project without making any weird additions to the project properties? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that your IDE (Netbeans) has the classpath configured appropriately for compilation, but that your runtime classpath is not configured appropriately. You would benefit from using a build tool such as [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/overview).